How to validate a string input passing to float type dto
How to validate a string input passing to float type dto?
I can pass any type of float values from 1.0 to 99.99. However, when I pass through 99A.99, it returns error 400 Bad Request
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Float` from String \"99A.99\": not a valid `Float` value

DTO
public class BookDTO {

    @NotNull
    @DecimalMin(value = "0.00", inclusive = true, message = "Price should not be less than 0.00")
    @DecimalMax(value = "99.99", inclusive = true, message = "Price should not be more than 99.99")
    private Float price;

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}

I want to make sure that all inputs passing is a float type. Have not really found any luck checking internet. I checked chatgpt and it was repeatedly suggested to do Create a Custom Validator Annotation from string to float.
Below is what I tried:
ValidFloatFormat
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FloatFormatValidator.class)
public @interface ValidFloatFormat {

    String message() default "Invalid float format";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

FloatFormatValidator
public class FloatFormatValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidFloatFormat, Float> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Float value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true; // Let @NotNull handle null values
        }

        try {
            Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(value)); // Try parsing to check format
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

DTO (updated)
    @NotNull
    @ValidFloatFormat(message="INVALID FLOAT")
    @DecimalMin(value = "0.00", inclusive = true, message = "Price should not be less than 0.00")
    @DecimalMax(value = "99.99", inclusive = true, message = "Price should not be more than 99.99")
    private Float price;

I am still getting the same bad request error.
Additional information:
Full response:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-07-11T14:18:03.787+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Float` from String \"9a9.99\": not a valid `Float` value",
    "path": "/api/books"
}

Expected sample response (simplified):
{
    "timestamp": "2024-07-11T14:29:40.473398987",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "errors": {
        "genre": [
            "size must be between 5 and 10"
        ],
        "title": [
            "size must be between 5 and 20",
            "Title should be alphanumeric Proper Noun case"
        ]
    }
}

Reason why the expected response is simplified instead of the default (very long) @Valid response:
Controller
    public ResponseEntity<?> createBook(@Valid @RequestBody BookDTO bookDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ValidationErrorResponse validationErrorResponse = new ValidationErrorResponse();
            validationErrorResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            validationErrorResponse.setError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name());
            for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
                validationErrorResponse.addError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(validationErrorResponse);
        }

        BookDTO createdBook = bookService.createBook(bookDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(createdBook);
    }

ValidationErrorResponse
public class ValidationErrorResponse {

    private Map<String, List<String>> errors = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, List<String>> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    ... // other columns

    public void addError(String field, String errorMessage) {
        errors.computeIfAbsent(field, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(errorMessage);
    }
}

For the invalid float, I would like to return the default message that was set in the DTO ("INVALID FLOAT")

have you tried removing the 'A' from the value you try to pass?

I don't understand the problem really, I want to make sure that all inputs passing is a float type. - the current setup is already stopping invalid input, you get 400 response, although the error is coming from the json parser. What do you want to happen for 99A.99?

@Stultuske yes I can pass valid float values. However, I want to make sure that all values passed are float values (not string, etc)

@Chaosfire. I want to stop it from going through. I have a @Valid in my controller where it will return validation object. I want to include the string not a valid float message.

public boolean isValid(Float value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { -> what do you think happens here if you pass a String?

@Mr.Kenneth You are already stopping it from going through, at an even earlier point actually. First the payload is being deserialized into BookDTO. Then the object is validated. 99A.99 can't be deserialized into float, so the json parser fails, it never reaches the point of object validation triggered by @Valid. What you want to do is not possible unless you deserialize the price into a string - private String price;, the docs of @DecimalMin state that it supports validation on char sequences. I guess it may work if you are fine with the strings.

@Chaosfire I have added additional information about what is my expected result and actual result. When I try to add all 3 invalid data at the same time (title, genre, price) the full response is returned showing the error while the other 2 is not even declared.

@Stultuske. same message.

After going at it back and forth, the only change I made that works is variable type from Float to String
private Float price;

↓
private String price;

Then change all affected parts of the code. I guess Java/Spring Boot throws an exception message that Float types could not accept String as an input (even before custom validation is executed). I was expecting that my custom validation comes first before spring boot argues that it is not possible.
Moving forward, I might have to add a separate class for this (Validation Class) where it will accept everything in String or Object then validate it before passing to DTO.
